# Classes do Bootstrap para criar colunas com espaço

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Quero entender as classes do **Bootstrap**, quando utilizar as com `span` e `offset`, e como conseguir dar um espaço entre as colunas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para mover as colunas você usa a classe **`.col-md-offset-*`** . 
A classe incrementa margem a esquerda da coluna. Por exemplo, **`.col-md-offset-4`** move `.col-md-4` depois 4 colunas.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">.col-md-4 .col-md-offset-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">.col-md-3 .col-md-offset-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">.col-md-3 .col-md-offset-3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">.col-md-6 .col-md-offset-3</div>
</div>
```

E o resultado é este

[image: render html]

Comment: <div class="row"> <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">.col-md-6 .col-md-offset-3</div>
</div> funcionou perfeitamente.